# Problema al ir de un fragment a otro usando FragmentTransaction

Tags: java, android-studio

Saludos, veran soy nuevo en este foro asi como tambien en androi. Hace un par de dias vengo haciendo una pequeña aplicacion basado en un tabbed activity el cual tiene cuatro pestañas (SETUP, STATUS, CHARTS Y SETTINGS) basados en un fragment y los elementos de cada pestaña esta contenida en un Relative layout. El problema que tengo es que no logro pasar de un fragment a otro a partir de un alertDialog. Hasta el momento este es el codigo que estoy usando.

```
    AlertDialog.Builder alertSettings =new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
alertSettings.setCancelable(false);
alertSettings.setMessage("Do you want to make some configuration for data sampling?");
alertSettings.setTitle("Configure Sampling");
alertSettings.setPositiveButton( "OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        SettingsFragment goSettings = new SettingsFragment();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, goSettings);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
} );
alertSettings.setNegativeButton( "Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        StatusFragment goStatus = new StatusFragment();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, goStatus);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();*/

    }
} );
alertSettings.show();
```

Alguien que me pueda ayudar con este problema por favor, gracias de antemano.

Comment: Agrega el código completo de tu Activity.

Answer (score 0):

Bueno este es el codigo del fragment

```
public class SetupFragment extends Fragment{

EditText editName,editMake,editModel,editSerial,editDate,editCapacity,editCA,editCCA;
Button loadButton,saveButton;
ConnectionSQLiteHelper connectorSetup;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_setup, container, false);
    connectorSetup = new ConnectionSQLiteHelper(getActivity(),"db_batmon",null,1);
    editName = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.editSetup1);
    editMake = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.editSetup2);
    editModel = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.editSetup3);
    editSerial = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.editSetup4);
    editDate = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.editSetup5);
    editCapacity = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.editSetup6);
    editCA = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.editSetup7);
    editCCA = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.editSetup8);
    loadButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.bSetupLoad);
    saveButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.bSetupSave);
    saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"Saving...",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            final AlertDialog.Builder alertSave = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            alertSave.setCancelable(false);
            alertSave.setMessage("Do you want to save the battery data?");
            alertSave.setTitle("Save Data");
            alertSave.setPositiveButton( "OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    String nameBat = editName.getText().toString();
                    String makeBat = editMake.getText().toString();
                    String modelBat = editModel.getText().toString();
                    String serialBat = editSerial.getText().toString();
                    String dateBat = editDate.getText().toString();
                    String capacityBat = editCapacity.getText().toString();
                    String caBat = editCA.getText().toString();
                    String ccaBat = editCCA.getText().toString();
                    if(!nameBat.isEmpty()&&!makeBat.isEmpty()&&!modelBat.isEmpty()&&!serialBat.isEmpty()&&!dateBat.isEmpty()&&!capacityBat.isEmpty()&&!caBat.isEmpty()&&!ccaBat.isEmpty()){

                        SQLiteDatabase dbBat = connectorSetup.getWritableDatabase();
                        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                        values.put(Utilities.FIELD_NAME,nameBat);
                        values.put(Utilities.FIELD_MAKE,makeBat);
                        values.put(Utilities.FIELD_MODEL,modelBat);
                        values.put(Utilities.FIELD_SERIAL,serialBat);
                        values.put(Utilities.FIELD_DATE,dateBat);
                        values.put(Utilities.FIELD_CAPACITY,capacityBat);
                        values.put(Utilities.FIELD_CA,caBat);
                        values.put(Utilities.FIELD_CCA,ccaBat);

                        Long idResult = dbBat.insert(Utilities.TABLE_BATTERY,Utilities.FIELD_ID,values);
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"ID Register: "+idResult,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        dbBat.close();
                        AlertDialog.Builder alertSettings =new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                        alertSettings.setCancelable(false);
                        alertSettings.setMessage("Do you want to make some configuration for data sampling?");
                        alertSettings.setTitle("Configure Sampling");
                        alertSettings.setPositiveButton( "OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                                SettingsFragment goSettings = new SettingsFragment();
                                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, goSettings);
                                fragmentTransaction.commit();
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"Opening Settings...",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        } );
                        alertSettings.setNegativeButton( "Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                                StatusFragment goStatus = new StatusFragment();
                                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, goStatus);
                                fragmentTransaction.commit();
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"Opening Status...",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        } );
                        alertSettings.show();
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"Complete all fields please",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            } );
            alertSave.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new AlertDialog.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"Cancelled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } );
            alertSave.show();
        }
    });
    return v;
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    editDate.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus){
                DateDialog dialog = new DateDialog(v);
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                dialog.show(fragmentTransaction,"DatePicker");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}